# How to use RichTextCtrl events?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am not sure I quite get how to use RichTextCtrl events.

What I want is to get the text that is typed into the RichText into another string.

I though I would be able to do this with `EVT_RICHTEXT_CHARACTER` but when I type

`self.textField.Bind(wx.EVT_RICHTEXT_CHARACTER,self.textEdit)`

where self.textField is the RichTextCtrl I get an error saying:

`Cannot find reference 'EVT_RICHTEXT_CHARACTER' in '__init__.py | __init__.py | imported module wx'`

Do I need to import something else to make it work? If so - what? I didn't quite get what it says in the wxPython documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are simply mis-assigning the event to `wx` when it should be something else.
Below, because I import `wx.richtext` as `rt` the event will be in `rt`
i.e. `rt.EVT_RICHTEXT_CHARACTER`

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test RichText Superscript')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.rtc1 = rt.RichTextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(10,10),size=(350,90),style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER|wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT|wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT_FACE)
        self.rtc2 = rt.RichTextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(10,110),size=(350,90),style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT|wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT_FACE)
        self.rtc1.Bind(rt.EVT_RICHTEXT_CHARACTER,self.textEdit)
        self.Show()

        attr_super = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
        attr_super.SetTextEffects(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUPERSCRIPT)
        attr_super.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
        attr_super.SetTextEffectFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUPERSCRIPT)
        self.rtc1.WriteText("Is this super?")
        self.rtc1.SetStyle (7, 13, attr_super)

        attr_sub = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
        attr_sub.SetTextEffects(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUBSCRIPT)
        attr_sub.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECTS)
        attr_sub.SetTextEffectFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_EFFECT_SUBSCRIPT)
        self.rtc1.AppendText ("\nIs this sub?")
        self.rtc1.SetStyle (23, 26, attr_sub)
        self.rtc1.AppendText ("\nIs this normal?")

        self.rtc2.WriteText("Is this super?")
        self.rtc2.SetDefaultStyle(attr_super)
        self.rtc2.WriteText("\nThis is super?")

    def textEdit(self, event):
        char = event.GetCharacter()
        self.rtc2.AppendText(char)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```